# draw out as frequency divider from circuit

Tags: flipflop, logic-gates, frequency-divider

I have this circuit and I have to get the out "S" but have no idea how The initial condition is D0 and Q1 = 0

[image]

And i just have what I guess is q0, and with that i supposse S is 0 and then all 1, but not sure.

I hope you can help me. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: You can't figure out Q1 unless you know what D1 is and it's missing from your timing chart. Modify your sketched answer to include D1 and repost. We won't do your homework for you but will prompt you. Note that it's "D0" and not "d0" for consistency.

Comment: Yes use "Proper or UPPER Case" for all labels  Clk, Q0 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by now you should have posted a solution

here's my 2 bits* worth done on excel
[image]

(*) pun intended . Each FF is one bit memory register or cell thus you have a 2 bit synchronous Up counter using Q0,Q1  or down counter using the inverted outputs.

Sorry I was wrong, It's divide by 3.  Must be old age or Murphy's Law. but it's good for you to know when to admit your misteaks!.  I stand corrected
[image]

Comment: Don't do the guy's homework for him! And use proper capitalisation and punctuation! ;^)

Comment: @TonyStewart I update what I think it was and sent it, but now that I see your answer is better because I forgot the Q1 is flip flop master from the Q0 :( thanks anyway.

Comment: we use the arrow icons to disagre/agree with answers

Comment: I believe your diagram is wrong; you have D1 = 1 when Q0 = 1 and Q1 = 0; D1 can only be 1 if both Q0 and Q1 are 0 since it is fed from a NOR gate.

Comment: good eye tcrosley

Answer (score 1):

I believe the circuit is a divide by three, as shown below (I modified the timing diagram that Tony drew):

[image]

Because of the NOR gate feeding into D1, D1 can only be 1 when both Q0 and Q1 are 0:

```
Q0   Q1   D1
------------
 0    0    1
 0    1    0
 1    0    0
 1    1    0
```

Comment: WTG Mr Crosley,

Answer (score 0):

With the two d-flops you can have four possible states at the "Q" outputs (00, 01, 10, 11).  Pick one to start -- it may as well be 00.  What are the "D" inputs for this state?  These become the next state outputs.  Continue until the states start repeating. Did all four possible states show up?  Probably not.  What is the missing state?  What happens if you start with that missing state and clock it?

You need to see what happens with all states.  It's pretty easy to solve this by observation, since it's got so few possible states.  In more complicated designs you will probably have to use more formal methods.